# sshfs: chroot all non-root users to specific directory

Tags: ssh, sftp, sshfs

On a server I need unrestricted ssh access for root, and restricted for all other users.

I would like to restrict all non-root users to:

- no ssh login
- only allow mount `/mnt/data/` using `sshfs`

I see `sshd_config` allows to use `Match User`, ie:

```
Match User john
  ChrootDirectory /mnt/data/
  ForceCommand internal-sftp
  AllowTCPForwarding no
  X11Forwarding no
```

but how can I match all users except root ?

Comment: I posted an answer, but it is not completely clear to me if the "credible and/or official sources" part refers to the general feasibility/security of your solution or to the specific "how to match root only" question.

Comment: @fra-san - I am not sure what you mean. Do you imply that while this solution works technically, it is not secure ?

Comment: No, I was just wondering if you were looking for some endorsement of a specific configuration by the original authors or other authoritative people. Actually, what you are doing is advised in many knowledgeable sources (the [Arch Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/SFTP_chroot) being one example).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The Match directive in `ssh`'s configuration files supports negation. But it looks like negating conditions in `sshd_config` is a bit tricky: you have to write

```
Match User="!root,*"
```

to have subsequent directives applied to all users except root.

Here is the relevant documentation: from `man sshd_config`:

> Match   Introduces a conditional block.
>    ...
>    The match patterns may consist of single entries or comma-separated lists and may use the wildcard and negation operators described in the PATTERNS section of ssh_config(5).

And from `man ssh_config`:

> PATTERNS
>   A pattern consists of zero or more non-whitespace characters, ‘*’ (a wildcard that matches zero or more characters), or ‘?’ (a wildcard that
>        matches exactly one character).
>   ...
>   Note that a negated match will never produce a positive result by itself.
>   For example, attempting to match "host3" against the following pattern-list will fail:
>
> ```
> from="!host1,!host2"
> ```
>
> The solution here is to include a term that will yield a positive match, such as a wildcard:
>
> ```
> from="!host1,!host2,*"
> ```

Hint found in [this article](https://access.redhat.com/solutions/289073) on Red Hat Customer Portal.